# How can I put a line break in the text of an IF statement in a plain text email template?

Tags: email-template

I am trying to put a line break inside of an IF statement within a plain text email template.

The template is like this:

```
Hi {!Receiving_User.FirstName}, 

{!IF(Receiving_User.Profile = "Desired Profile","Text will go here if the profile matches the desired profile. Want this line to be a new paragraph", "")}
```

I was accomplishing this with multiple IF statements on each line but I have multiple statements like this and if the desired profile does not match then each IF statement puts a blank line into the email and I have 8 of them so the email can end up looking like:

> Hi User, 
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  Text from first
>   matching statement here.

I have tried putting a \n in the text and a BR() and also tried creating a Custom Label called NewLine with a value of - and then putting `SUBSTITUTE($Label.NewLine, "-", "")` in but not sure I have that in the code properly to determine if that will work.  I tried

```
{!IF(Receiving_User.Profile = "Desired Profile","Text will go here if the profile matches the desired profile." +SUBSTITUTE($Label.NewLine, "-", "")+ "I Want this line to be a new paragraph", "")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Normal plain text templates are incredibly limited in what they support; they only support a small subset of all the functions in the Formula help topic.

Instead, use a Visualforce email:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test" recipientType="User" >
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
<apex:outputText rendered="{!recipient.Profile.Name='Desired Profile'}">
Text will go here if the profile matches the desired profile.

I Want this line to be a new paragraph
</apex:outputText>
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a way to do this (probably not perfect in code terms but it worked). Do not break line between all your if statement, instead enter a break line in your iftrue result right after the "

**Your Example:**

```
Hi {!Receiving_User.FirstName}, 

{!IF(Receiving_User.Profile = "Desired Profile","
```

Text will go here if the profile matches the desired profile. Want this line to be a new paragraph",

```
"")}{!IF(Receiving_User.Profile...
```

Enter your breakline before your "Iftrue" text so each time your statement is true it will break a line, enter all your IF statements inline so no further break line will be created